# Decision regions in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

In a part of my classification code

```
def plot_decision_regions(X, y, classifier, resolution = 0.02):
    markers = ('s', 'x', 'o', '^','v')
    colors = ('red', 'blue', 'lightgreen', 'gray', 'cyan')
    cmap = ListedColormap(colors[:len(np.unique(y))])

    x1_min, x1_max = X[:, 0].min() -1, X[:,0].max() + 1
    x2_min, x2_max = X[:, 1].min() -1, X[:,1].max() + 1
    xx1, xx2= np.meshgrid (np.arange(x1_min, x1_max, resolution), np.arange(x2_min, x2_max,resolution))
    Z = classifier.predict(np.array([xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()]).T)
    Z = Z.reshape(xx1.shape)
    plt.contourf(xx1, xx2, Z, alpha= 0.3, cmap = cmap)
    plt.xlim(xx1.min(), xx1.max())
    plt.ylim(xx2.min(), xx2.max())

    for idx, cl in enumerate (np.unique(y)):
       plt.scatter (x=X[y == cl, 0], y= X[y == cl, 1], alpha=0.8, c=colors[idx], marker= markers [idx], label = cl, edgecolor = 'black')
```

When I graph my data, I have the graph that appears below. My question is: The straight line that separates the samples, from which part of my code does it appear? I think it is because of the `Z` function, but seeing the values ​​it has, I see that it has both positive and negative values, which left me confused

[image: Petal length vs petal length]

Comment: `plt.contourf(xx1, xx2, Z, alpha= 0.3, cmap = cmap)` color your decision regions.

Comment: inside that line of code,  is the straight line produced by the output values ​​of `z`?

Comment: In short yes. In details, `z` is the prediction of the features from `xx1` and `xx2`, i.e. every single point on the mesh. Therefore, the line is a bit wiggling. You can smooth out by reducing the `resolution` parameter, but that comes with a cost of computation time on `classifier.predict`.